# Does vapor latent heat depend on temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

Adding energy to water makes it's temperature increase. This continues until it reaches 100 °C (at 1 atm) when it turns to vapor with a vaporization energy of 2257 kJ/kg. But if we lower the pressure on the water, it can start boiling at lower temperatures. In this case, would it's vaporization latent heat still be 2257 kJ/kg?

If not, how does the latent heat of water depends on boiling temperature or vapor pressure?

Comment: Why would you expect it to stay constant?  What do you think the heat of vaporization is at the critical point?

Comment: The heat of vaporization decreases as the temperature increases, until it becomes zero at the critical temperature.